# How can I achieve asp.net's Master Detail or include a header link in header section using simple html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, eclipse

I have this site http://abhisheksimion.cjb.net, where I would like to keep my top banner and menu part available in all the pages, I know this can be done using frames, but this way I'll get a visible divider between my pages (banner and main body). I do not want that. Can anyone suggest me a clean way. Thanks :)

Also how can I include some page in the header or footer part, so that the page gets loaded!

Comment: are you using a server side language?

Comment: @JohnP: no server side, cjb.net is a site that offers site space and hosting for free with limitations.

Comment: @Abhishek Well, some kind of server side is required. You could also try including via JS but that's really ugly too

Comment: @JohnP: Right now I am not planning to spend any cash, since this is my very 1st site, may be later, still isn't there any other way I can achieve this? something like invisible frame or so?

Comment: @AbhishekSimon I don't think so. If you're creating static pages, why not maintain the header/footer on your side? You won't have a common file, but some programs can automate updates (like dreamweaver)

Comment: @JohnP: hmm, I am using Eclipse, does it do the same?

Comment: @Abhishek I don't think so. Maybe with a plugin

Comment: @JohnP: How can I include some page link in my `header` or `footer` so that it loads automatically in every page,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an include file (.inc extension) and call it from all you pages like this:

```
<!--#include file="../../inc/header.inc-->
```

If you were writing server side, Master pages would be an ideal solution.

Here's an example on an inc file:

```
                <% if(_CP.cShowBackBtn || _CP.cShowActMenu){%>  

            <script src="../../js/public/ActMenu.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script> 
            <LINK href="../../css/public/ActMenu.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

            <tr>
            <td height="1">
                <table width="80%"  border="0">
                    <tr>
                    <% if(_CP.cShowBackBtn){%>
                        <td>
                            <%=_CP.cOutBackBtn%>
                        </td>
                    <%}%>
                    <% if(_CP.cShowActMenu){%>
                        <td width="100%">
                            <DIV id="idActMenuHolder" dir="<%=DIR%>" class="clsActMenuLine" onmousemove="cActMenuOver()" onmouseout="cActMenuOut()">    
                                <%=_CP.cOutActMenu%>
                            </DIV>
                        </td>
                    <%}%>
                    </tr>
                </table>                            
            </td>
            </tr>
            <%}%>
```

As you can see, it doesn't have the `html`, `body` tags, because it is called in the middle of an html file

Comment: Thanks. So this `.inc` will contain simple html page content? any link to help with. Also this html comment goes inside the `header div` ?

Comment: Yes, it can contain html, css, js - it acts like any html page. It doesn't have to include the `html`, `head`, `body` tags, if they are already used in the html file that is calling the include file. I added an example inc file in my answer

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick for me using jquery, where **#header** is the div id for header, and **/temp/header.html** is the header html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#header').load('/temp/header.html', function() {});  
});
```